# How to describe the solutions of a Pell equation which contains a rational number

Tags: pell-type-equations

Let $N(x,y) = x^{2}-dy^{2} $ with d a strictly positive integer and not a square and m an non-zero integer.
$$ N(x,y) = m
$$
is the general form of Pell's equations which is mostly studied in the literature.
But what happens when m is not an integer anymore ? More specifically, consider this equation :$$ x^{2}-2y^{2} = \frac{1}{4} $$
According to my research positive (x, y) solutions are described by
$$
x+y\sqrt{2}=(\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{2})(3+2\sqrt{2})^{n}
$$
with $ n \in \mathbb{N} $

Does this expression really generate all the possible positives solutions ? And if so, how can I be sure ? Is there some sort of condition I can use ?

When integer solutions exist in Pell's equation, these conditions [[1](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=617&lmm=0)] can be applied and solutions can be described.
I was inspired by this method, even if my solutions are not integers. So that's why I'm not sure my result is correct even if it seems to work numerically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you put in a non-integer for $m$, you're certainly not talking about integer solutions any more.  Your formula will give solutions where $x$ and $y$ are either integers or half-integers.  Indeed, if  you take $x=s/2$ and $y=t/2$, the equation $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 1/4$ becomes $s^2 - 2 t^2 = 1$, and you're back to Pell's equation.